# ASP.NET MVC 3 Routing Issue with Un-conventional folders

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In a website I am working on, I place all my images inside "images" folder such that "/images".

ASP.NET MVC 3 is throwing an exception saying it cannot find a controller for "images".

Any trick to do with the route table?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you feel the need to fight against the grain.  Certainly, it can be done.  but why?  What are you gaining?

Comment: Nothing much, but the website already is developed and i cant afford changing that now. Any hint on how to do the workaround? Thanks

Comment: You've never heard of search and replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("images/");
```

This will prevent routing from trying to resolve a controller for requests containing this folder.

Comment: I actually added    routes.IgnoreRoute("images/{*pathInfo}")  Thanks